# Ubuntu Software Center "software requires mouse, but none setup" win installing a purchased app

Tags: software-center, input

Fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 64bit on Asus laptop. Everything works as expected except this odd warning.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something to get understanding why this warning appear:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/developer-portal/+bug/1029301

Comment: While this definitely answers the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include a brief summary of what you consider to be the important point(s) in your answer, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an external mouse. Some games do require external mouse attached to the system.